# Codeigniter 4 sum many columns in multiple join table giving wrong results

Tags: mysql, join, sum, codeigniter-4, multi-table

I am doing my first project using Codeigniter 4. I am trying to make a summary page which consist of some sum from different columns and different tables.

Here is the tables :

table project

id  project_name
1   project 1
2   project 2

| id | project_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | project 1 |
| 2 | project 2 |

table leading

| id | id_project | permit | job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

table man_hours

| id | id_project | branch | base | sum_manhours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I've tried this :

ProjectModel :

```
    public function getSummary()
    {

        $this->join('leading', 'leading.id_project=project.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->join('man_hours', 'man_hours.id_project=project.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->select('sum(permit) as permit, sum(job) as job');
        $this->select('sum(sum_manhours) as sum_manhours');
        $this->select('project.id, project.project_name');
        $this->groupBy('project.id');
        $result = $this->findAll();

        return $result;
    }
```

Controller Project :

```
public function manhours(){
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Summary',
            'project' => $this->projectModel->getSummary()
        ];

        return view('summary/view-summary-manhours', $data);
}
```

The results :

| id | project name | permit | job | sum_manhours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | project 1 | 8 | 8 | 12 |
| 2 | project 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

It seems like the query working twice that's why is giving the wrong results, how do I fix this? I am really looking forward for the solution, thank you so much for reading my question, even more for giving me solution.